# How to fix 508 Resource Limit is reached in Godaddy. Entry process shows max exceeds

Tags: wordpress

My sites - in last days - have been interrupted and going down showing the following page

> Resource Limit Is Reached
>   The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.

cPanel is showing "Entry Processes" 125/125. My sites don't get huge of traffic, it's almost personal for now.

PHP processes show "No PHP Processes found." as I read from some articles.

I have tested by backup websites file on localhost and delete from server root folder and place a simple PHP file on server but no progress same result.
My website is [link here](http://awtadoman.com/).

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Its due to memory exhausted issue on your disk of your hosting.

Please delete the excess and unwanted files.

Also contact Customer Support of GoDaddy hosting provider.